# Belt Tensioning

Tags: anet-a6, belt

I have printed off some upgrades for my Anet A6 for tensioning the belt on the Y and X axis. I was wondering how much deflection the belt should have. I would think being to tight will stress the machine.

Comment: It should be tight but not to tight. If you overtighten your belts it can do more wrong than good. Also if you are using a acrylic frame of some sort, can cause the frame to flex and bend. This may cause it to snap further into the future. As for the perfect amount of tension, i could not tell you. use common sense whilst feeling the tightness of the belt. It should be tight enough so its not sloppy but lose enough that it can still move up and down when you push on it.

Comment: @Granny is there a good way to tell how much tension would be perfect? I press on the belt and I am think maybe a 1/2" of deflection is good... maybe?

Comment: I edited my comment just after you made the above comment. Please read what I have written over there :)

Comment: @Granny Sounds fairly easy, I just don't want to go to tight, but I don't want that it to loose, but now that I have gotten this upgrade set in place I am getting more circles than ovals :), thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to know the proper deflection I should have on the belt. What I have read is for every inch of belt (25.4mm) it should deflect 1/64 of a inch (.4mm).

I found this information on this [Website](https://best3dprinter.stan-tech.com/3d-printer-belt-tension-is-it-important).